# How to remove the contents of process.env from the build file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

When built from react, process.env is exposed in Sources of the developer tool.

But I don't want to expose it.

Isn't it strange that I know that you need that value to get the code working on the web client, but I don't want to expose it in the dev, so I hide it in .env, but after the build process, I have to expose it?

What this means is that writing in plain text be the same as use .env because "web clients are bound to be exposed anyway." It's very strange.

If wrong how do I solve it?

[exposed env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L74wF.png)

Comment: If you have any data that can't be exposed there, you should never use that data in the frontend application. Use http-only secure cookies for example.